# Stop processing and evaluate next value in foreach loop

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to search and check for the duplicate details that is available in the database using php.The user enters several names and then a phone number to check for the duplicates. Below is my function. I just cropped out some parts because it was too long.

```
function gtc($names,$phone)
{

    $pageNumb=20;
    $position = array(5);

    $sepname=explode(",","$names");

foreach ($sepname as $sepname1)
{
    for ($page=0;$page<=$pageNumb;$page=$page + 1)
    {
    $turl="http://192.168.111.2119/search.php?qry=$sepname1&page=$page";

    $search=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($search,CURLOPT_URL,$turl);
    curl_setopt($search,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($search,CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
    curl_setopt($search,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,true);
    $result=curl_exec($search);

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($result);

        $xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
        $elements = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@id='inf']");

        foreach ($elements as $element)
        {

            $position[$sepname1] = $position[$sepname1] + 1;

            foreach($position as $key=>$val)

            $contct  = $element->getElementsByTagName("contact")->item(0)->nodeValue;

            if (preg_match("/$phone/i",$contct)) {
                echo "Found In Database>";

            }

            }

        ob_flush();
        flush();

        }
}
    }


?>
```

The function works perfectly but the only problem that I am having is although a match is found it goes until the last page which is given in the for loop and then goes through the next name. I would like to know is it possible to make when a match is found stop processing and then search for the next name?

I don’t want to use exit(); because it completely stops the execution

The input format is as below
User inputs names: john, Sam, Michael, Steve
Phone number:0084554741

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are likely looking for [`break`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

```
// output numbers 1,2,3,4
foreach( range(1,10) as $number) {
    if($number === 5) break;
    echo $number, PHP_EOL;
}
```

and/or [`continue`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

```
// output only even numbers
foreach( range(1,10) as $number) {
    if($number % 2) continue;
    echo $number, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add that you can tell continue how many loops to escape.

Comment: @Kristoffer I leave that for the OP to find out at the respective manual pages :)

Answer (score 2):

@Gordon offered the formally correct answer, a "best practices" answer would be to split your function into logical parts (especially as you mention it's too long), for example:

```
 function search($term) {
    $xml = loadXmlFromRemoteHost();
    if(!$xml)
       echo "An error occured";
    $found = findTermInXml($xml, $term);
    if($found)
       echo "Found In Database>";
```

The search function contains the loop in question and uses "return" to exit the loop (and the function) when it finds something:

```
    function findTermInXml($xml, $term) {
        foreach(...whatever...) {
             if(...some condition...)
                 return true;
        }
        return false; // nothing found
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://pl.php.net/break

http://pl.php.net/continue